# jquery load data on click event without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, calendar

I have a event calendar in my blog. it's working as my expectation except click event. because on click next or prev link months not changing its data. normally if click prev link it should render previous month but not working. same as next. how to solve? please

[Calendar]

```
<dl class="data">
    <dt>Archive</dt>
    <dd class="calendar">   
        <?php
            date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dhaka");
            if(!isset($_REQUEST['month'])){$month = date("m");}else{$month = $_REQUEST['month'];}
            if(!isset($_REQUEST['year'])){$year = date("Y");}else{$year = $_REQUEST['year'];}
            if(!isset($_REQUEST['day'])){$day = date('d');}else{$day = $_REQUEST['day'];}   
            $timestamp = mktime (0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
            $monthName = date("F", $timestamp);
            $prev_year = $year;
            $next_year = $year;
            $prev_month = $month-1;
            $next_month = $month+1;
            if($prev_month == 0 ){$prev_month = 12;$prev_year = $year - 1;}
            if($next_month == 13 ){$next_month = 1;$next_year = $year + 1;}
            $prev_month = str_pad($prev_month, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $next_month = str_pad($next_month, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        ?>
        <div class="table">
            <div class="tr caption">
                <div class="th L">
                    <a id="cprev" href="javascript:void(0);">&lsaquo;</a>
                </div>
                <div class="th monyer"><?php echo($monthName.'-'.$year); ?></div>
                <div class='th R'>
                    <a id="cnext" href="javascript:void(0);">&rsaquo;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='thead'>
                <div class="td">S</div>
                <div class="td">M</div>
                <div class="td">T</div>
                <div class="td">W</div>
                <div class="td">T</div>
                <div class="td">F</div>
                <div class="td">S</div>
            </div>
            <?php
                $monthstart = date("w", $timestamp);
                $lastday = date("d", mktime (0, 0, 0, $month + 1, 0, $year));
                $startdate = -$monthstart;
                //Figure out how many rows we need.
                $numrows = ceil (((date("t",mktime (0, 0, 0, $month + 1, 0, $year))
                + $monthstart) / 7));
                //Let's make an appropriate number of rows...
                for($k = 1; $k <= $numrows; $k++){
            ?>
            <div class="tr days">
            <?php
                //Use 7 columns (for 7 days)...
                for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
                    $startdate++;
                    $startdate = str_pad($startdate, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); //Make dates leading zero
                    if($startdate <= 0){//If we have a blank day in the calendar.
            ?>
            <div class="td L">
                <?php echo("&nbsp;");?>
            </div>
            <?php }elseif($startdate > $lastday){echo('<div class="td R">&nbsp;</div>');}else {
                if(in_array($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$startdate, $dates) && $startdate == date("d") && $month == date("m") && $year == date("Y")){ ?>
            <div class="td today">
                <span class="triangle-up-left"></span>
                    <a href="blog/archives/<?php echo($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$startdate); ?>"><?php echo($startdate); ?></a>
            </div>
            <?php
            } elseif($startdate == date("d") && $month == date("m") && $year == date("Y")){?>
            <div class="td today"><?php echo($startdate); ?></div>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <?php if(in_array($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$startdate, $dates)) { ?>
            <div class="td days">
                <span class="triangle-up-left"></span>
                <a href="blog/archives/<?php echo($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$startdate); ?>"><?php echo($startdate); ?></a>
            </div><?php }else{ ?>
            <div class="td days"><?php echo($startdate); ?></div><?php }?>  
            <?php } } } ?></div><?php } ?>
        </div>
    </dd>
</dl>

<script>
    var maxPages = {{ page.last }};
    var Pmonth = <?php echo($prev_month);?>; 
    var Pyear = <?php echo($prev_year);?>;
    var Nmonth = <?php echo($next_month);?>; 
    var Nyear = <?php echo($next_year);?>;
</script>
```

[Jquery]

```
$('#cprev').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var pmonth = Pmonth;
    var pyear = Pyear;
    var url = 'http://localhost/phalcon3/blog?month='+pmonth+'&year='+pyear;
    $.post(url,{pmonth:"pmonth",pyear:"pyear"},function(){

    });
});
```

Comment: Can you pls check is there any javascript error occurs after clicking on previous link or not

Comment: Having No error

Answer (score 1):

Setting the href to `href='#'` will prevent a redirect.

Also you should return false at the end of your jquery function to prevent the default action:

```
$('#cprev').on('click', function(e){
    var pmonth = Pmonth;
    var pyear = Pyear;
    var url = 'http://localhost/phalcon3/blog?month='+pmonth+'&year='+pyear;

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: url
        data: {pmonth:"pmonth",pyear:"pyear"},

        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(){
        }
   });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Setting the href to a hash will also jump the user to the top of the page when the link is clicked

Comment: @winseybash not always true!

Comment: @atoms I stand corrected, didn't know that.  I wrote my answer at the same time as you so didn't see yours until I had posted mine.  It's a very simple fix so our answers were bound to be similar!

Comment: i'm using href="javascript:void(0);" and follow your instruction but not going to previous month.

Comment: no worries winseybash.. @babymachinery it doest look like you are doing anything with the post data, maybe why nothing is happening

Comment: what should i do? i want to post request to month and year

Comment: The OP is already preventing the default action using `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @jeroen do you have a better idea as to what the OP is asking for? "the page always refresh but i want to change calendar without page refresh"

I am a little confused, do you wish to update the users view or the DB?

Comment: No, I'm just saying that if the javascript executes correctly, the page will not reload as `e.preventDefault()` will prevent that.

Comment: I see. I had assumed that as the page was refreshing preventDefault() wasnt working. Now I'm unsure if they want to update calendar or the database :S

Comment: In console the request is sending with status code 200 OK but previous month not rendering. whats my wrong?

Comment: @babymachinery So the page is not refreshing? You should clean up your question, only post the relevant code and state what the exact problem is.

Comment: you may be not understanding! i want if i click prev button it should load previous months days same as next but its not showing prev months days in console its just shows that request is posted if posted why not it rendering desired data?

Comment: @babymachinery `because on click next or prev link the page always refresh `. Right, I am not understanding...

Comment: @babymachinery, you arent returning anything from the ajax request. Have updated my answers ajax function. Should print data to the console.

Comment: @atoms shouldn't the second ajax function be `error` instead of `failure`?

Comment: its not showing my calendar data but loads page's another data in consol

Comment: then your target url isnt correct or your not returning the correct/expected information.

Answer (score 0):

`e.preventDefault()` does not always stop the page refreshing.

Add `return false` to the end of your jQuery click handler like so which should stop the page reloading:

```
$('#cprev').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var pmonth = Pmonth;
    var pyear = Pyear;
    var url = 'http://localhost/phalcon3/blog?month='+pmonth+'&year='+pyear;

    $.post(url,{pmonth:"pmonth",pyear:"pyear"},function(){

    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: i have no problem in e.preventDefault(); its working. also page not refreshing but desired data not loading

Comment: @babymachinery then please think about rewording your question.  It is really not clear what your issue is.

Comment: I need to reload my calendar's data

Comment: just think why i want refresh less click event? because of to show calendar month days i its not happen is this code useful?

Comment: i think have to do something in $.post(url,{pmonth:"pmonth",pyear:"pyear"},function(data){
        .... Here some thing to load like: $('.calendar').html(data); ....
    }); But i'm not clear